# Scheduled Task in Spring waiting for other task of the same scheduler

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have in my xml file something like

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="idOfScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="update1" cron="...">
    <task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="delete2" cron="...">
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="idOfScheduler" pool-size="5">
```

The problem is that when method `update1` takes very long, method `delete2` is not executed until `update1` finishes. Is it because both tasks are scheduled in the same scheduler (it is configured with a max pool of 5)? Could one point out to the documentation that describes this part?

Comment: a quick google search for "spring scheduler" could point you to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html (first result here)

Comment: Show us your executor.

Comment: I added the definition of my scheduler. Nothing else is defined with "idOfScheduler".